# Is a distance expressed as a value, a length, or a distance?

Tags: nouns

I would like to know which noun is the best.

> The distance between them can be set to any **distance/length/value**.

Comment: All three seem okay to me, although I'd probably avoid repeating the word *distance* in most cases. Really, though, I would need much more context to say much more.

Answer (score 0):

I would use

> Length. The distance between them can be set to any length.

But the length can be set to many values.

Answer (score 0):

I would use **value**, not because of the word *distance* but because of the verb *set*. Someone setting a thing -- a dial, caliper, vernier, some other mechanical thing-that-gets-set -- usually sets it to a certain value.